# How to hide autocomplete box on Blur in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't solve a problem. Could someone help me?
I'm building a form and have an autocomplete box. The problem is that if I click somewhere on a page (except for the suggestion item) it doesn't hide. Where should I add `setIsAutoCompelte(false)` so that it hides?

State

```
// if true then show the box
const [isAutoComplete, setIsAutoCompelte] = useState(false);
```

onHandleChangeInput (if input.length > 3)

```
// show the box
setIsAutoCompelte(true);
```

onSuggestionClick (if I click on item in autocoplete box)

```
// hide the box
setIsAutoCompelte(false);
```

I do not provide full code because it's too big and I'm sure nobody would take a look at it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating the state in that element's `onBlur` event?  You could also look into something called a "click away listener", for which there are a variety of examples.

Comment: @David you mean add onBlur on input? Like this onBlur={()=> setIsAutoCompelte(false)} ...no changes at all. Might because of setIsAutoCompelte(true) in handlnputChange (onChange event)

Answer (score 0):

You could have an onClick on `App` that changes the state if the clicked target didn't have the className of the input. You'd need to apply a className such as "autoCompleteBox" to every element/component where you want `isAutoComplete` to be true.

```
const clickAnyWhereBut = (e, className) => {
    if (!e.current.target.classList.contains(className)) {
        setIsAutoCompelte(false); /* you have a typo for "complete/compelte" */
    }
}

<div className="App" onClick={() => clickAnyWhereBut("autoCompleteBox")}></div>
```

This is a lot easier if you're using redux because you wouldn't need to pass down the `setIsAutoCompelte`[sic] state.